# Search a list in list of lists by first two elements

Tags: python, list

Let's say we have a sorted list of lists:

`l_of_l = [ [1,2,1], [3,4,2], [3,4,5], [3,4,7], [9,10,8], [11,12,9] ]`

Sorted by the third value.

Task - to create a new list of the lists with unique first two digits and the smallest third digit.

Expected output:

`new_list = [ [1,2,1], [3,4,2], [9,10,8], [11,12,9] ]`

We don't have here `[3,4,5], [3,4,7]`, cause we already have an element that starts with `3,4`.

Since we already have a sorted list, my idea is to compare `x[:-1]` and take the first match which will include the smallest third digit by default.
But I completely stuck with writing proper code.

The lists can contain chars and integers.

Thank you.

Comment: *"I am completely stuck"* is very vague. What is the problem with executing your idea?

Comment: My biggest problem is to compare the first two elements from the given list with the two first elements in the new list. And if they match - skip, if don't match - add a list with all three digits into the new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is already sorted by the third element, you can use temporary dictionary to remove duplicates:

```py
l_of_l = [[1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 2], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 7], [9, 10, 8], [11, 12, 9]]


tmp = {}
for a, b, c in l_of_l:
    if (a, b) not in tmp:
        tmp[(a, b)] = c

print([[*k, v] for k, v in tmp.items()])
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 2], [9, 10, 8], [11, 12, 9]]
```

Comment: Very nice soultion! Thank you.
You will have my upvote once I got enough of reputation.